# Ajax Post no envia datos con cierto texto

Tags: ajax, string, textarea

Esto es muy curioso,  tengo este codigo que envia con POST datos a un archivo, todo funciona con normalidad, sin embargo cuando unicamente pongo algun texto especial, no me funciona generandome un error 403 orbidden en el archivo que recibe la informacion.

En resumen, con casi cualquier texto puesto en el textarea del form funciona sin problemas, sin embargo unicamente con este texto y cualquier otro texto raro que ya nos habia pasado antes.

Este es el codigo:

```
    $("#guardar_item").submit(function(event) {
        var parametrosnew = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(parametrosnew);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/items.php',
            data: parametrosnew,

            success:function(data){
                $(".items").append(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                $("#guardar_item")[0].reset();
            }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Y este es el texto que me genera el error:

```
*Servicio puntual, renovacion No aplica
* Diseño Web que por Promocion incluye Optimizacion Onpage para SEO
* En caso de no adquirir este servicio la optimizacion le saldria 100$
* Este costo incluye migracion de sitio web y dominio al 100% GRATIS
```

Si uso ese texto en el campo textarea, me da un error 403, en el documento items.php, pero si uso cualquier otro texto, no!
Debo aclarar que no se trata de caracteres especiales en el string, dado que ya he probado con otros textos que tambien llevan caracteres especiales y funciona sin problema.

Alguien podria darme por favor alguna pista del porque sucede esto? en 1 año casi, solamente ha pasado unas 3 veces. No suele pasar nunca, pero esas raras ocasiones siempre es lo mismo, con algun parrafo aleatorio exclusivamente.

Saludos!

ACTUALIZACION: Viendo la pestaña red en Consola curiosamente me sale que la respuesta 403, sale con una pagina de Wordfence, Adjunto captura...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Repito que esto solo pasa cuando pongo el texto de arriba, si uso otro texto no genera dicho error.

Comment: Puede agregar la petición, presiona F12 y ver a la pestaña de red, allí está la solicitud completa como la envía, para saber que detalles hay.

Comment: Ya he subido las capturas, no se si seran suficientes. Gracias por ayudar :)

Comment: Alguna sugerencia, ayuda o algo mas de lo que podria estar pasando?

Comment: En respuesta que mensaje arroja?

Comment: Me da respuesta en consola lo siguiente:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Osea que me dice que el archivo items.php, que es al que hacemos el llamado con AJAX; da un 403. Pero repito, eso solo pasa cuando usamos ese texto de arriba. Pero cuando usamos otro texto no pasa nada, envia sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar enviar las pediciones controladas. ejemplo que acepten o envien JSON para poder manipular mejor los datos que envias y las respuestas que quieres.

```js
  $("#guardar_item").submit(function(event) {
        var parametrosnew = { parameter: $(this).serialize() }
        console.log(parametrosnew);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/items.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: parametrosnew,

            success:function(data){
                $(".items").append(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                $("#guardar_item")[0].reset();
            }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Es igual, ya habia hecho la prueba pero con "JSON" en mayusculas, lo acabo de probar con minusculas, y el problema persiste. Solo con ese texto de ejemplo de arriba, con otros textos da normal.

Comment: Alguien mas que pueda darme alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?